# Preselect react select with condition

Tags: reactjs, select, default

I have select

```
<Select
 options={itemsArray}
/>
```

using `defaultValue={itemsArray[0]}` I can preselect with 0 object from itemsArray.
object has id and name.

Also I have seperate variable with id and name desiredVariable
How can I compare which itemsArray id coresponds to desiredVariable id so I can set default value of select correctly ?